# connection generated by signalr embedding signalr/hubs/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=abc123

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain, signalr

I had created chat application using signalr. I faced problem that I was unable to open multiple tabs so to solve that I used cross domain concept.

When I am running the website locally it is not showing any error message and working fine.

But when I am hosting website to server then it is raising following error-

example.com/signalr/hubs/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=42x80fo64OLWftVAXxJ1I1bTarAL2eRdRXwlVdx-UtM5KGb6RorETiKlxv8ebJG-_dl8x7NoZw1DJYrW-ECo0gm-lNxIe61V3mxGkoanucScvvnQDQC8vi5UbsGAkNPXD1pH5XA4Tv6FPmVFul3jXY8XR1k3tjdNcDfwihI_atIAJ8msO8BdvV9pbscat0DP0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22g2bmshub%22%7D%5D&groupsToken=3pGUI3di_lU7WAhlavII7A9cNpHs5M45qjkX40LnbYETPNicSzr3p3RdNKMaszYKbj8RLxIxGj9KP_gNk0Y3Y61-20hPDt5nTCWIKYsOR4raJQg1szNqUFkgpYwVDatDwE162GS5jj93IGIRjiS8yQ2&messageId=G%2C4%7CO%2C0%7CP%2C1%7CQ%2C0%7CK%2C0&userID=75&tid=7&callback=jQuery1800015164601150900126_1412139385725&_=1412139396182

I have defined the url in webconfig as-

and sets the hub url for connection in designer file as

$.connection.hub.url = "<%= HubURL%>";

Locally it is working fine and taking the same url as in web config file but when hosted, it embeds "reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=abc112..." to the connection and raising the above error.

Can anyone suggest me how to rectify the above error?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not include any actual error as far as I can see. What type of error are your getting? Your hub url should be "example.com/signalr" instead of "example.com/signalr/hubs", but I doubt that is causing your issue.

Comment: get example.com/signalr/hubs/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=42x80fo64OLWftVAXxJ1I1bTarAL2eRdRXwlVdx-UtM5KGb6RorETiKlxv8ebJG-_dl8x7NoZw1DJYrW-ECo0gm-lNxIe61V3mxGkoanucScvvnQDQC8vi5UbsGAkNPXD1pH5XA4Tv6FPmVFul3jXY8XR1k3tjdNcDfwihI_atIAJ8msO8BdvV9pbscat0DP0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22g2bmshub%22%7D%5D&groupsToken=3pGUI3di_lU7WAhlavII7A9cNpHs5M45qjkX40LnbYETPNicSzr3p3RdNKMaszYKbj8RLxIxGj9KP_gNk0Y3Y61-20hPDt5nTCWIKYsOR4raJQg1szNqUFkgpYwVDatDwE162GS5jj93IGIRjiS8yQ2&messageId=G%2C4%7CO%2%2C0&userID=75&tid=7&callback=jQuery1800015164601150900126_1412139385725&_=1412139396182

Comment: @halter73 above comment is the error. Due to which I messages are not sent. Which means SignalR client is not called by the SignalR server

Comment: And as you mentioned that my hub url should be "example.com/signalr" instead "example.com/signalR/hubs" but if I dont use hubs then although chat works properly but script is not generated when I hit the url without hubs, It raises error: Protocol error: Unknown transport. Script is only generated if we are using hubs with it. But chat process is working fine locally without hubs too. Does this effect the working??

Comment: Can anyone solve my problem??